# How to Hide or close a popupWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have a pdf in my root folder called "ert.pdf".

On button click I'm calling following thing:

```
function doPrint() {
    var opts = 'width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0';
    var newWindow = window.open("/ert.pdf", 'name', opts);
    newWindow.print();

}
```

It is working. Now I want to keep it hidden or close the window automatically without user interaction.

How can I do it?

Comment: are you using Telerik RadWindow?

Comment: no ,simple javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close javascript Popup Windows by following

```
newWindow.close();
```

[You can try this live example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close)

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
newWindow.close();
```

Once `newWindow` was open using `open()`, there will be no confirm message (http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml).